Not able to use X server on Ubuntu because of display error
Whenever I try to connect to my VcXsrv server, I get the error:  Can't open display: localhost:0.0. I have tried everything, but I can't seem to resolve this error. What do I do?

With WSL2, you no longer need a third party X server.

You may check the documentation for GUI apps in WSL.

VcXsrv is still needed to workaround bugs like this.
